# How to handle select all with select count in fSelect.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fselect

```
<select class="search_drop form-control" multiple="multiple" name="loading_point_id[]" id="loading_point_id">
  <option class="checkall" value="all">Select All</option>
  <option class="checkbox" value="option_01">Option 01</option>
  <option class="checkbox" value="option_02">Option 02</option>
  <option class="checkbox" value="option_03">Option 03</option>
</select>

<script>
   $('.search_drop').fSelect();

   $('.checkall').click(function() {
        if (!$('.checkall').is(":checked")) {
            $('.checkbox').addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $('.checkbox').removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

when I click on select all, it shows total 4 count (image 2) and by unselect some option, select all is till in the selected options as image 3.

[image]

Comment: Please include a [mre] to your question.\

Comment: You are only toggling the `selected` class there, but based on just that, the plugin probably doesn't even know, which options are currently selected. I even doubt that you checking your "select all" option even _actually_ selects the remaining options of the hidden original select element (which is still what the _submitted_ values will be based on, by the looks of it) - to me this looks like you are only doing "cosmetics", but have not modified the actual functionality behind this to begin with.